# Best font to use in body and header in a pdf document?

Tags: font, typography

I make a document/book on weight loss of about 20 pages, and I think of the font and size I should use in headlines and body text? The document will be available via pdf-file, so it should be easy to read both on screen and printed.

MS Word standard is Calibri on the body text and Calibri Light on headings. Is it safe to go with it or do you have any other suggestions? Personally I think is a bit too weak for the headlines but has no other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

As defaults go, calibri isn't a bad option. It's also generic and oft-used. You'd better speak to a designer or typographer. Perhaps on [graphicdesign.stackexchange.com](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com)?

Answer (score 0):

For a good typography primer, take a look at Butterick's ["Typography in Ten Minutes"](http://practicaltypography.com/typography-in-ten-minutes.html).

For body font size, use 10–12 points (depends on your typefaces). Heading size really depends on your stylistic preferences.

The typeface choice depends both on how you want to present the document. Calibri might imply that you just whipped up the document in Word, but is a better choice than most other fonts you're likely to find on your computer. If you want to use a system font, consult [Butterick's system fonts chart](http://practicaltypography.com/system-fonts.html). If you don't want to pay for a font, there are various Google font combinations recommended for the web that can be applied to printed materials as well.

Answer (score 0):

Body text is considered more readable in serif fonts. Headings are considered more readable as sans serif.

I'm a fan of Open Sans and Droid Serif, personally. They are my go-to combo. Both are available for download on Google Fonts.

12pt. is considered minimum readbility size for displays. I usually use 20-22pt. for headings and 16-18pt. for sub headings.

Answer (score 0):

Using a non-system font will increase the size of your PDF, so you may want to take that into consideration when using a font like Calibri that is not available in a Mac.